# Getting an error on splash screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(10040): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, 
but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
```

I'm using Samsung M31s as my main debug device and I've been getting this error for a long time and the migration steps are too complex for me. I've used other devices and emulators also and did not face any issues so maybe this is an issue with Samsung devices.
What changes should I do to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line from your Manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

This is deprecated and no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the issue of API ,you must have seen the API version in emulators,may be using the physical device i.e. in case of your samsung phone,your mobile may have a deprecated version,kindly see this and confirm.